# ASP.NET Core routing error

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a route like `http://localhost:63037/api/futuresMarginRuns/7/data` which is working however another controller API with route `http://localhost:63037/api/futuresMarginRuns/2018-07-11/data` is not working, even the breakpoint in the controller API is not hit.
Here are the API signatures

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("/api/futuresMarginRuns/{id}/data")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetFuturesMarginRunDataAsync(long id)
    {
        var data = await _repository.GetAllAsync(id).ConfigureAwait(false);
        return Ok(data);
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("/api/futuresMarginRuns/{runDate}/data")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetFuturesMarginRunDataByDateAsync(DateTime runDate)
    {
        var data = await _repository.GetAllAsync(runDate).ConfigureAwait(false);
        return Ok(data);
    }
```

In the first case I get json data but in the second one the breakpoint is not hit so looks like the route is not mapped to the API properly in which case I would expect an error, but i get empty `[]`

How can I the API to work?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add some [route constraints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-2.1#route-constraint-reference) to your routes.  Route constraints tell the routing engine that if `id` is supposed to be an int, only match that route if the text in that spot can be converted to an int (and similarly with dates, etc).

So I would change your routes to the following:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("/api/futuresMarginRuns/{id:long}/data")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetFuturesMarginRunDataAsync(long id)

[HttpGet]
[Route("/api/futuresMarginRuns/{runDate:datetime}/data")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetFuturesMarginRunDataByDateAsync(DateTime runDate)
```